# Regex pattern matching in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to split the data

```
rest = [" hgod eruehf 10 SECTION 1. DATA: find my book 2.11.111 COLUMN: get me tea","111.2 CONTAIN  i am good"]

match = re.compile(r'(((\d[.])(\d[.]))+\s(\w[A-Z]+:|\w+))')
out = match.search(rest)
print(out.group(0))
```

I found the pattern as "multiple decimal digit(eg:1. / 1.1. / 1.21.1 etc.,) followed by character till another multiple decimal digit(eg:1. / 1.1. /  1.21.1 etc.,) "

I want to split the data as

1. DATA: find my book

2.11.111 COLUMN: get me tea

111.2 CONTAIN  i am good

Is there any way to split the text data based on the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the expected matches using

```
import re
rest = [" hgod eruehf 10 SECTION 1. DATA: find my book 2.11.111 COLUMN: get me tea","111.2 CONTAIN  i am good"]
res = []
for s in rest:
    res.extend(re.findall(r'\d+(?=\.)(?:\.\d+)*.*?(?=\s*\d+(?=\.)(?:\.\d+)*|\Z)', s))

print(res)
# => ['1. DATA: find my book', '2.11.111 COLUMN: get me tea', '111.2 CONTAIN  i am good']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/z8kZjo)

The regex is applied to each item in the `rest` list and all matches are saved into `res` list.

**[Pattern](https://regex101.com/r/WGUgsY/2) details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=\.)` - there must be a `.` immediately to the right of the current position
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a `.` and then 1+ digits
- `.*?` - 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\d+(?=\.)(?:\.\d+)*|\Z)` - up to the 0+ whitespaces, 1+ digits with a `.` immediately to the right of the current position, 0 or more repetitions of a `.` and then 1+ digits, or end of string

Comment: It is not finding "1. DATA:" in string... how to make that

Comment: @Cybertron You have no `1. DATA..` in your string in the question. What are the exact requirements for the pattern? What type of context should it match?

Comment: Awesome!! working!! Thank you so much how can i find the logic of regex patterns please tell me

Comment: @Cybertron Use http://regex101.com or http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl to see what they match.

Comment: that didn't work completely please check the pattern

Comment: @Cybertron If you say something does not work, say what is wrong. I can't guess much without data example that fails. I removed space + uppercase letter pattern from the lookahead, is it fine now?

Comment: Got it
"  res.extend(re.findall(r'\d+(?=\.)(?:\.\d+)*.*?(?=\s*\d+(?=\.)(?:\.\d+)*|\Z)',s))  "
worked fine just changed the pattern accordingly.. Thanks @Wiktor